# Is there any good alternative struct for using inside switch case?

Tags: c#

I have switch case for showing text in my program. I wonder that can i use dictionary or enum for numbers and texts? Or is it good for using switch case like this?

```
string result;
int number = int.Parse(Console.Readline());
switch (number)
{
    case 1:
        result += "ten";
        break;
    case 2:
        result += "twenty";
        break;
    case 3:
        result += "thirty";
        break;
    case 4:
        result += "fourty";
        break;
     case 5:
        result += "fifty";
        break;
     case 6:
        result += "sixty";
        break;
     case 7:
        result += "seventy";
        break;
     case 8:
        result += "eighty";
        break;
     case 9:
        result += "ninety";
        break;
     default:
        result += "";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a little less verbose to use a `Dictionary{int,string}` in that scenario:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>(9)
{
    {1, "ten"},
    {2, "twenty"},
    {3, "thirty"},
    {4, "fourty"},
    {5, "fifty"},
    {6, "sixty"},
    {7, "seventy"},
    {8, "eighty"},
    {9, "ninety"},
};
```

---

```
string dictionaryEntry;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(number, out dictionaryEntry))
{
    result += dictionaryEntry;
}
```

Also, if you plan to do a lot of string concatenations, consider using [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of string for `result`.

> For routines that perform extensive string manipulation (such as apps that modify a string numerous times in a loop), modifying a string repeatedly can exact a significant performance penalty. The alternative is to use StringBuilder, which is a mutable string class.

Answer (score 1):

It may sound a little bit primitive, but if you know that strings are going to be in a consecutive order, why not to use a string array?

```
string[] array = new string[] { "ten",
                                "twenty",
                                "thirty",
                                ...
                                };

...

result += array[number-1];
```